# session->run slow down the speed of the code in another thread

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I create a thread for fetch image from video, and a thread for doing detection. The two threads are in different `cpu` core. However,  I find that the speed of fetch thread become slower if both of the two thread are running. The thread for detection use tensorflow `c++` api to do detection. I also find that if I comment the code of tensorflow `c++` api in detection thread, the speed of fetch thread will not become slower.
Why do the tensorflow `c++` api slow down the speed of another thread ?

Comment: Multiple threads will compete for resources. Perhaps the bottle neck is memory speed and not CPU speed?

Comment: tensorflow might run in more than one thread and thus demand all cpu cores